# Typescript: what is the Mac OSX command for the quote character concerning multiline?

Tags: angular, macos, typescript

I am pretty new to Angular 2 and and following the official tutorial (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html) I noticed that I have to use the ` mark for multi-line template strings (string interpolation).

As a Mac OSX user (french keyboard) do you have any advice how to type this quotation marks easily?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/532233/what-is-the-key-on-a-mac-keyboard

Answer (score 1):

> the back tick key is to the left of Return while you hold the Option key

Ref https://superuser.com/questions/532233/what-is-the-key-on-a-mac-keyboard